# Keep button from submitting form Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm learning JavaScript and am unable to make a button inside of a form that doesn't submit the form. There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932653/how-to-prevent-buttons-from-submitting-forms) but the most popular answer to specify `type="button"` doesn't work in my case and other answers involve jQuery, which I would like to leave out for now.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function submit(){
                alert("Yo")
        }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="submit()">
        <input type="button" value="Submit!" onClick="submit()" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Since you're not using a `type="submit"` the only reason your form would submit anything is because you literally call the `submit()` method when the button is clicked. (well, sort of.  it's actually form.submit()).  By default, a input of `type="button"` will not do a form submission unless you literally call `form.submit()`.

Comment: @Tibrogargan that is the problem. Once I changed the function name it worked perfectly! If you make it an answer I can accept it.

Comment: This is actually a really interesting question.  Since functions are scoped at the window level you would expect your `onClick="submit()"` to use the `window.submit()` method - but it's resolving to `form.submit()` when the input tag is created because the context was changed to the form.  I can't find that behavior documented anywhere - it might actually be browser dependent (or I just don't know the right place to look)

Comment: @Tibrogargan I tested in both Mozilla and Chrome, though I haven't tried in IE. But if you do find the documentation anywhere please let me know, I'd love to read it!

Comment: Turns out it's by design.  [Scope Changes During HTML Parsing](/questions/38296881/scope-changes-during-html-parsing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're not using a `type="submit"` the only reason your form would submit anything is because you're literally calling the submit() method when the button is clicked. (well, sort of.  It's actually `form.submit()` - the method you created is `window.submit()`).

By default, an input of `type="button"` will not do a form submission unless you literally call form.submit()

Answer (score 2):

Pass along the event as an argument in your `submit` function, and prevent its default behaviour:

```
function submit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('Yo');
}

onClick='submit(event)'
```

Answer (score 2):

Dating from the introduction of Javascript by Netscape Corporation, form element event handlers defined as *HTML attribute* values were provided with a special scope chain which searches properties of the element clicked and the form element ahead of searching the global object. [This was a convenience for web programmers and predated the introduction of a Document Object Model with standardized methods for access and manipulation.] Hence

```
<input type="button" value="Submit!" onClick="submit()" />
```

when clicked executes the anonomous function created from the HTML attribute string:

```
function( event) { submit()}
```

which searches its scope chain for `submit` and finds it as a property of the enclosing `form` object.  Possible solutions include

- explicitly specifying the global version of the function to execute:

  ```
      onclick="window.submit()"
  ```
- naming the global function something else, say "preSubmit", which does not conflict with the property of the form object:

  ```
      onclick="preSubmit()"
  ```
- adding the click event handler to the button in javascript after the button element has been created (only function specified in HTML have a special scope chain).

Section `19.1.6. Scope of Event Handlers" within [chapter 19](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch19_01.htm) of "Javascript the Definitive Guide" from O'Reilly is the only link that I have been able to find which discusses this.

---

*updated after @progysm's comment on another answer*

The scope chain of an HTML provided event handler is now covered in the HTML5 standard, under [internal raw uncompiled handler](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#internal-raw-uncompiled-handler), list item 1.10, which indicates the lexical scope of the handler includes the element clicked, the form it belongs to (if any) and the document object. I would caution against relying on this too heavily: some browsers used to include every parent object of a clicked element in its scope chain, not just its form and document.

Comment: Ah, yes, the `window.submit()` works well, too, and adds some clarity to the situation. +1

Answer (score 2):

**To prevent your button from submitting**, you can either:

1. Use **`preventDefault()`** on the **`onsubmit`** event of the `<form>` or
2. Use **`return false`** at the end of the operation on the **`onclick`** event of the button.

**The code**:

```
<html>
    <head></head>

    <body>
        <form name = "myForm" method = "POST">
            <input name = "button" type="submit" value="Submit!"/>
        </form>

        <script type = "application/javascript">
             document.forms.myForm.onsubmit = function(e) {
                 e = e || event;
                 e.preventDefault();
             }

             document.forms.myForm.button.onclick = function () {
                 // Your code
                 return false; // Prevents the button from trying to submit
             }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Notes**:

- Be sure to use the **`method`** attribute in the `<form>` tag as it's required.
- **`e = e || event`** means that **`e`** will be equal to **`e`** in all the browsers that recognise it and equal to **`event`** in browsers that recognise **`event`**.
- **`document.forms.[form name].[input name]`** is another way to get an element based on its name, in contrast to **`document.getElementById()`** which requires the **`id`** of the element, which have not set in your HTML.

**You can test the code's functionality live with the following snippet**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html>
        <head></head>

        <body>
            <!-- The form we don't want to submit -->
            <form name = "myForm" method = "POST">
                <input name = "button" type="submit" value="I will not submit!"/>
            </form>
          
            <!-- The form we want to submit -->
            <form name = "myForm2" method = "POST">
                <input name = "button2" type="submit" value="I will submit!"/>
            </form>

            <script type = "application/javascript">
                 // For the form we don't want to submit
                 document.forms.myForm.onsubmit = function(e) {
                     e = e || event;
                     e.preventDefault();
                 }

                 document.forms.myForm.button.onclick = function () {
                     console.log("NOT Submitted!");
                     return false;
                 }
                 
                 // For the form we want to submit
                 document.forms.myForm2.button2.onclick = function () {
                     console.log("Submitted!");
                 }
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: 1 preventDefault on the form submit works great. As it doesn't require all buttons inside the form has `type="button"` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function onFormSubmit()
{
  console.log('FORM SUBMITTED');
  return false;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>
<body>
  <form name="myForm" onsubmit="return onFormSubmit()">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit form! [input type = submit]" /><br />
    <input type="button" value="Submit form! [input type = button, onclick = form.submit]" onClick="return onFormSubmit();" /><br />
    <!-- in real test change onClick behavior 
    return onFormSubmit(); 
    to:
    form.submit();
    Here I used onFormSubmit() because when you calling form.submit() browser doesn't dispatch onsubmit event -->
    <button>Submit form! [button]</button><br />
    <a href="#" onClick="return onFormSubmit();">Submit form! [a, onclick = form.submit]</a><br /><br />
    <input type="button" value="Click me, no submit! [input type = button]" /><br />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to conditionally consume the event or not, simply return true or false from your handler function, like so...

**JavaScript:**

```
function validate() {
    var valid = true;
    // the following two validation functions would return a Boolean.
    valid = valid && validateUsername();
    valid = valid && validatePassword();
    // If validation is fine, return true and this allows post to continue.
    // If validation is not fine, return false and this disallows the submission from going ahead.
    return valid;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<form name="frmTest" id="frmTest"
    method="post" action="example.action"
    onsubmit="return validate();">
</form>
```

If you don't need it to be conditional, just return false, of course.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works in native javascript. Doesn't prevent return key in inputs, it does what it should - stop a form from submitting on enter

```
function preventReturnKeyFormSubmit(){
    //listen to key press events
    window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
        //set default value for variable that will hold the status of keypress
        pressedEnter = false;

        //if user pressed enter, set the variable to true
        if(event.keyCode == 13)
            pressedEnter = true;

        //we want forms to disable submit for a tenth of a second only
        setTimeout(function(){
            pressedEnter = false;
        },100)

    })

    //find all forms
    var forms = document.getElementsByTagName('form')

    //loop through forms
    for(i = 0; i < forms.length; i++){
        //listen to submit event
        forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(e){
            //if user just pressed enter, stop the submit event
            if(pressedEnter == true) {
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        })
    }

}
//run this function inside document onload/domready/ or if using jquery .ready()
preventReturnKeyFormSubmit()
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply make it return the function, and return false

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function submit(){
                alert("Yo");
return false;
        }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="submit()">
        <input type="button" value="Submit!" onClick="return submit()" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This won't work @MoustafaS, because submit() inside onClick is form.submit() (see how the scope is modified in inline event handler in HTML5.